# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Qualtrics'

Tags: python-3.x, qualtrics

I am trying to follow the example available in

https://github.com/dwallach1/Qualtrics_API

Once I do the following

```
!pip install Qualtrics
```

It gives me the following

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Qualtrics (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for Qualtrics
```

Then I follow the webpage provided

```
import Qualtrics
```

It gives me

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Qualtrics'
```

Have anyone tried it before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be importing this file

https://github.com/dwallach1/Qualtrics_API/blob/master/src/qualtrics.py

and you should not be installing it from `pip`

If you want to use a `pip` package, do have the python package below, check it out!

`pip install py-qualtrics-api`

https://pypi.org/project/py-qualtrics-api/